# Is it common to use an adjective as a noun without ‘the’ or the following word in the press headlines?

Tags: grammar

Washington Post November 29 issue reports Pope Francis has been encouraging Vatican’s charity activity under the headline: Pope ramps up charity office **to be near poor, sick**. It begins with the following sentence:

> “Pope Francis has ramped up the Vatican’s charity work, sending his
> chief alms-giver and a contingent of Swiss guards onto the streets of
> Rome at night to do what he usually can’t do: comfort the poor and the
> homeless.”
>
> http://www.washingtonpost.com/national/on-faith/pope-ramps-up-charity-office-to-be-near-poor-sick/2013/11/29/ac9cd9a6-58d0-11e3-bdbf-097ab2a3dc2b_story.html?tid=pm_pop&wpisrc=nl_most

Is it common to spare “the” or “people” in front, or after “poor” and “sick” like this in journalism English? To me you can not save much space by sparing 'the,' and ‘to be near poor, sick” sounds like “feel like being poor and sick.

Comment: It's "headline English", using a minimum of words (especially function words) so what's left can be set in larger type

Comment: What Stoney says: it is not used (and not acceptable) outside headlines.

Comment: @StoneyB Headline or any English, this is unacceptable, when the meaning is not preserved anymore. *Poor* is not the same as *the poor*. And *poor* is not a noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here are some relevant portions that might help from an educational article about writing headlines:**

http://www.uncp.edu/home/acurtis/Courses/ResourcesForCourses/WritingHeadlines.html

*What is a headline?*

A headline is an abstract sentence

Usually it is only five to ten words

It is a complete thought

*Grammar*

**Don't use the articles a, an and the. They waste space unnecessarily.**

So while articles would be required in written or spoken English, headlines are specifically an exception to the rule.

Comment: "Don't use the articles a, an and the." Only so long as add nothing to the meaning, or not change the meaning.